# Is the canonical isomorphism $\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ isometric with respect to the Frobenius norm?

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, tensors, matrix-norms

Let $p\in\mathbb N$ and $n_1,\ldots,n_p\in\mathbb N$. Assume the tensor product space $\bigotimes_{i=1}^p\mathbb R^{n_i}$ is equipped with the unique inner product $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_{\bigotimes_{i=1}^p\mathbb R^{n_i}}$ satisfying $$\left\langle\bigotimes_{i=1}^px^{(i)},\bigotimes_{i=1}^py^{(i)}\right\rangle_{\bigotimes_{i=1}^p\mathbb R^{n_i}}=\prod_{i=1}^p\left\langle x^{(i)},y^{(i)}\right\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }x^{(i)}\in\mathbb R^{n_i},\tag1$$ where $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$ denotes the Euclidean inner product. For any $I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,p\}$ there is a canonical$^1$ isomorphism $$M_I:\bigotimes_{i=1}^p\mathbb R^{n_i}\to\mathbb R^{\prod_{i\in I}n_i\times\prod_{i\in I^c}n_i}$$

> The question is: Are the isomorphisms $M_I$ isometric? It clearly depends on the matrix norm chosen on $\mathbb R^{\prod_{i\in I}n_i\times\prod_{i\in I^c}n_i}$. I would like to show the isometricness for the Frobenius norm$^2$.

---

$^1$ Assume that we have fixed an isomorphism converting a multiindex into a single index.

$^2$ if $\left(e^{(n)}_1,e^{(n)}_n\right)$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $A,B\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, then the Frobenius inner product of $A,B$ is given by $$\langle A,B\rangle_F=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\langle Ae^{(n)}_i,Be^{(n)}_i\right\rangle.\tag2$$

Comment: Long story short: the answer is yes, and if you identitfy $\otimes$ with the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) (equivalently, if you identify $\Bbb R^{m} \otimes \Bbb R^n$ with $\Bbb R^{mn}$), then you find that this isomorphism is simply the [vectorization map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom And how do we prove it? Or do you have a reference?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okay, I think it's rather simple: $\mathbb R^I$ equipped with $\langle x,y\rangle:=\sum_{i\in I}x_iy_i$, $x,y\in\mathbb R^I$, is a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space for any finite nonempty set $I$. And $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is just a shorthand notation for $\mathbb R^I$ with $I:=\{1,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,\ldots,n\}$. So, the Frobenius norm is actually the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^I$. From this observation it's at least clear to me that all $\mathbb R^{\prod_{i\in I}n_i\times\prod_{i\in I^c}n_i}$, for varying $I$, are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: I didn't have the time to write an answer before, but that's pretty much it. Another perspective: the map $e_i^{(m)} \otimes e_j^{(n)} \mapsto  e_i^{(m)}\langle e_{i}^{(n)}, \cdot \rangle$ takes an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis, and therefore extends to an isometric isomorphism.